# How to understand "As luck would have it"?

Tags: compounds

> When you create macros, you may want to have a clear and easy way to run each macro. A
> basic button can provide a simple but effective user interface. **As luck would have it**, Excel offers a set of form controls designed specifically for creating user interfaces directly on spreadsheets.

How to analy the content of **As luck would have it**, for I just feel it is weird? May you show me some examples from short sentences to long sentences?  I can understand **As luck**, but why can he added **would have it**?

Comment: It's an idiomatic expression meaning "lucky", and in my opinion, it's not worth analyzing to learn any grammar, other than historical grammar. I'm not sure what the original intent of the odd wording is, but in my mind, it means **"luck" is an entity, and if "Luck" could decide how things are, this is the way they would have chosen** as in **"Luck" would want Excel to offer a set of form controls...**

Answer (score 2):

"As luck would have it" means that a personified *luck* wanted it to be so.
Of course, it's just a figure of speech.
The phrase could be replaced with either "luckily" or "unluckily", depending on how the speaker feels about the events spoken of.

The phrase is shown in two dictionaries that I found by searching at onelook.com.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-luck-would-have-it)

> **by chance**:
> *We ran out of petrol on the way home, but as luck would have it, we were very near a garage.*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20luck%20would%20have%20it)

> **as luck would have it
> —used to say that something happened because of good or bad luck**
> *Our car broke down on the road, but as luck would have it, there was a garage nearby.*
> *I arrived a little late and, as luck would have it, the last ticket had just been sold.*

[formatting added to dictionary definitions]